# Error with .jar file -- attempts to locate file in jar folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, path, executable

Hopefully this will make some sense. I'm new to Java and while I've built .jar artifacts before, I have never had to build a program that takes another file as input. I'm running into a weird problem and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Basically, I have a Main.java class that calls a .txt file and passes it to another class, myClass.java. I generated a .jar file with IntelliJ, which inserted itself inside its own folder.

To make things easier, here is the basic structure of my program.

```
/src
   /com.myProgram
       Main.java
       input.txt
       MyClass.java

/out
   /artifacts
       /myProgram_jar
           myProgram.jar
```

And here is a basic version of what's in Main.java

```
myClass mc = new myClass("input.txt");
```

I tried running the .jar file with the command "java -jar myProgram.jar", and I get the error "The system cannot find the path specified". I ran getCanonicalPath() on input.txt. Apparently my program is looking for input.txt in out/artifacts/myProgram_jar instead of in the src/ folder.

What can I do? Even when I put the full path to force the program to look in the src/ folder, it will still attempt to look in the myProgram_jar folder and throw an error. So I cannot execute the file at all. Any suggestions for solving this error are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just add the code for myClass (btw convention is that Classes should start with an uppercase Letter).

Comment: @Jürgen could you verify what you mean?

Comment: Just post the code. Sorry for writing ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

When you build to jar file, it's not a File anymore. A File is only a physical file on the file ystem.
So have 2 way to fix it:

**1.** You export the txt file to system as D:/New folder, then you get this file with path of this file.
**2.** You can try this:

```
try {
      URL url = new URL(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().toString()+your path to file in structre);
      InputStream in = url.openStream();
} catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(PrepareGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Numb. 

The only problem with the first suggestion is that I will need these files to work on another computer, so I can't really save them to a drive. 

So you're suggesting that I put an altered code such as this in my Main.java class, when I'm trying to call input.txt?

Comment: Also, for the prepareGUI() statement, what class can I import for that?

Comment: You can try this:
First you use this to get your file:
`java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new java.util.jar.JarFile("your path jar file");
 java.util.Enumeration enumEntries = jar.entries();`
then, in while loop `while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {}`, you get files by `java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) enumEntries.nextElement();`, compare `if(file.getName().contains("input.txt")) {is = jar.getInputStream(file); fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f); while (is.available() > 0) { fos.write(is.read()); }}`. is : InputStream, fos: FileOutputStream. And prepareGUI is my class